# Root element is missing when trying to Publish

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

It has been a while since I've published my app to Azure. During that time frame, I've upgraded my system from 32-bit to 64-bit meaning a fresh install of Windows and Visual Studio. And Visual Studio Update 3 came out and was applied. When I went to publish an update today, I received the following:

*The following exception was thrown trying to publish: Root element is missing.*

My web.config file looks fine so I don't think it's [this issue](http://mgadler777.wordpress.com/2013/03/25/microsoft-lightswitch-2012-root-element-is-missing-error/).

The app works fine in debug mode so I don't think it's any of the .lsml files as is mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ceb03f75-11a9-4bf7-a771-d964a5827821/root-element-is-missing-get-after-receive-out-of-memory-message-in-vis-studio).

And I tried [this procedure](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/david_kidder/archive/2012/12/05/declaring-lightswitch-publish-wizard-bankruptcy.aspx?Redirected=true) to hand edit the .ls3proj file but it didn't seem to help.

I previously had an issue trying to publish when I upgraded from the standalone LightSwitch 2011 to Visual Studio 2012. I was able to overcome that issue using the method described in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7bcdee0f-046d-48b8-9584-6411f64dbcb1/no-longer-able-to-publish).

Attempting to use this same method resulted in my new project has a full screen error saying "*There are critical errors in the application definition metadata...*" and 210 individual errors (max errors reached).

The first error, "*Cannot create unknown type '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/LightSwitch/2010/xaml/model}GlobalAttributeGroup'.*" Doesn't make sense because that line in the .lsml is identical from the old project to the new project.

The second error, "*Could not find any application definition in the project.*" Which I do not understand at all.

I am able to publish a simple "Hello, world" style app to my Azure account.

What could be causing this? How can I get more information about exactly which element is causing the issue? The log produced by running `devenv /log` was not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt Thalman was able to solve my problem over in the [Microsoft Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ecdff8dc-8190-4d32-9080-ce6430d9e27a/root-element-is-missing-when-trying-to-publish?forum=lightswitch). The ServiceConfiguration.cscfg and ServiceDefinition.csdef were missing from the project when checked out of version control. Copying those over from a new project restored my ability to publish.